# Is Knapsack Feasibility and Knapsack with Unit Values NP-Hard?

Tags: complexity-theory

It is well known that the maximization problem of Knapsack if NP-hard. How about just finding a feasible solution i.e. objective is set to zero?

And also if we set the [values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) to all one (not the weights) in the objective of the Knapsack problem is it still NP-hard i.e. $\max v^Tx$ where $v=(1,1,1..,1)$?

Comment: We expect you to do some research and make an effort on your own before asking here.  So, what have you tried before asking?  Have you tried looking for efficient algorithms?  Have you studied the standard reductions to prove that Knapsack is NP-hard?  What does "testing whether a feasible solution" exists even *mean* for Knapsack?  The empty set (taking no items) is always a feasible solution, and achieves an objective of zero.  I think you need to spend more effort thinking through this particular question, before asking.

Comment: @D.W. I should have mentioned non zero feasible solution. For non-zero feasibility is it NP-hard ?Thanks.

Comment: What do you think?  Did you read the part where we expect you to make a serious effort before asking and to show us what you've tried?  (in the question, please)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just finding a feasible solution is in $P$.  The empty set is a feasible solution.  It achieves an objective of zero.  So, the answer to "does a feasible solution exist?" is always "yes!" (to the extent that the question is even well-defined).  Similarly, the answer to "is any solution whose value is $\ge 0$?" is always "yes!".  Thus, those problems are not NP-hard.

When all values are one, there is also a trivial polynomial-time algorithm to find the optimal solution.  You should be able to find it yourself: just try a few examples, and you will quickly discover the trick.

Comment: @Is it to take the smallest weight item on wards?

Comment: @triomphe, what do you think?

Comment: I think it is correct. Would like to confirm. thanks.

Comment: OK, @triomphe, so you have a candidate algorithm and you want to know whether it is correct.  What techniques do you know for checking that?  Have you tried running it (by hand) on some small example problem instances?  Have you tried writing a proof of correctness?  These skills will be very helpful to you -- this is a great chance to practice them (you should practice them every chance you get!).

Comment: I have not studied these formally. I can imagine a general example where this sorting (from low weight to higher) wold give highest value. But I don't know if that is a proof.